# What does this plus symbol mean in Pug?

Tags: pug

I keep seeing the plus symbol popping up in code:

```
block content

    +javascriptIncludeTag("")
```

I've tried googling but I can't find the answer anywhere. It might have something to do with Knockout js but I don't know enough about Pug or Knockout

Answer (score 4):

That is the syntax for a Pug [mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html). It's not related to KnockoutJS.

From the [Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html):

> Mixins allow you to create reusable blocks of Pug.
>
> ```js
> //- Declaration
> mixin list
>   ul
>     li foo
>     li bar
>     li baz
> //- Use
> +list
> +list
> ```
>
> ```html
> <ul>
>   <li>foo</li>
>   <li>bar</li>
>   <li>baz</li>
> </ul>
> <ul>
>   <li>foo</li>
>   <li>bar</li>
>   <li>baz</li>
> </ul>
> ```